# JavaFX ListView - Scroll with button press

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-2, javafx-8, fxml

I have a listView that contains my data, but instead of scrolling using the scroll bar, i need to be able to press a button to scroll up (if the listview can scroll up) and a button to scroll down (if the listview can scroll down)

Anyone know how i would go about this?  I have checked the listView, and there seems to be no function to scroll up or down.

Ideally i would like to know if there are properties against a listView that tell me the

- Maximum Y position that the listView can go to
- Current Y postition that the listView is scrolled to

Using these values i can code the rest.

Comment: `ListView` has a `scrollTo()` method; maybe you can use that? Or maybe wrap the `ListView` into a `ScrollPane`?

Comment: What difference will it make it i use a scrollPane with the listView inside?

Comment: Never mind, i see that scrollPane has a getVMin, getVMax and setVValue.Thanks

Comment: @fge hmm ... be careful: (as with all virtualized controls) scrolling is the task of the ListView's VirtualFlow - I would expect strange thingies happen when explicitly adding an inherently scrollable control to a scrollPane. Fighting the design is rarely a good idea. OP: don't understand why you cant use scrollTo?

Comment: @fge I doubt that wrapping the ListView in a ScrollPane will work, because I doubt that ListView reports the total content height as its preferred height.

Comment: @kleopatra `scrollTo` makes the given item visible. That means it does nothing when the given item is already in the viewport.

Comment: ListView is virtualized, items only exist when you scroll to them via a factory mechanism, you could use to display millions of items, but only allocates the ones in view...

Comment: @kleopatra I am not even sure what you mean about virtualized control? The fact that for instance there is an identical separation as for `TreeView` for instance, where you have both `TreeCell` and `TreeItem`?

Comment: @fge what happened when you typed "javafx virtualized control" into your favorite search engine? yeah... exactly :-)

Comment: @TomasMikula just checked (tableView, though, 8u40b23): scrollTo(index) makes index the first line in the viewport, independent on its visibility

Comment: @kleopatra ok, my interpretation of the Javadoc was different, but still, this is not what the OP wants.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, i removed the listView, and used a ScrollPane with a VBox.  Then i added my items to the VBox instead.  I had to make changes to the items i was adding to the listView originally, but this seems to work nicely.

I can now use the get/set property VMin, VMax and Vvalue on the scrollPane.

Comment: re-inventing the wheel is a waste of time, nearly always ;-) Anyway, still don't understand your _exact_ requirement. Even if the properties you seem to require are not exposed on ListView, you could lookup the ScrollBar installed by VirtualFlow and access all its functionality

Comment: I could (and probably will do so at some point anyway) expose the scrolling API on [Flowless](https://github.com/TomasMikula/Flowless), which will get you the desired functionality and virtualization at the same time. But if you don't have a whole lot of items, then you don't care about virtualization and VBox will work just fine for you. // cc: @kleopatra

Answer (score 0):

There is [Flowless](https://github.com/TomasMikula/Flowless) which acts as a simplified(*) (and more efficient) ListView. It has [scrollX(dx)](http://www.fxmisc.org/flowless/javadoc/org/fxmisc/flowless/VirtualFlow.html#scrollX-double-) and [scrollY(dy)](http://www.fxmisc.org/flowless/javadoc/org/fxmisc/flowless/VirtualFlow.html#scrollY-double-) methods that you can use to scroll the content.

(*) It does not support selection and inline editing out of the box, but can be implemented on top of it.